# How can we save the data into the LocalDB in windows form

Tags: c#, database, winforms, localdb

Whenever I try to save the data into the local data base it never save. And when I re-run the windows form localDB data has reset Each time I run Windows form In Debug. I tried many ways but it didn't worked.
So what should I do.

Comment: This typically happens when the database is part of the projects where under properties for the database under Solution Explorer Copy to Output Directory is set to Copy always. If you want to persist changes set this property to Copy if newer. If the database is not part of the project we need more details.

Comment: Are you using `AttachDbFilename` in the connection string?

Comment: The vital step you may  be missing, as Karen and Charlieface allude to, is that every time you build the app, the build process copies a new blank DB out to the bin folder, the app runs, edits the db in the bin folder, then you change the code, build it again, the build process overwrites the edited DB with a fresh blank one and runs the app. VS is wonderful in that you can add a file based database into the project and it makes some things easy, but the default behavior to replace the DB every time the build runs is very confusing for newbies